# Conditionally add to jQuery .when

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, .when

When my page loads, I make one AJAX call, and then another conditionally upon what is on the page. I want to call a function at the end of both; how do I do it?

```
var dfd = $.when( $.ajax(...) );

if( $("type").val() == "something" ) {
  dfd.when( $.ajax(...) );
}

dfd.then(function() { 
   // final code
});
```

I can't find much about adding to `$.when "conditionally"` or "later" as those search terms are too close to the original purpose of the promise itself, so I just get the standard usage of `$.when(a, b).then(c)`

Thanks

Comment: `dfd` should be equal to `$.ajax(...)` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code should look more like this:

```
var dfd = $.ajax(...);
var dfd2 = $.ajax(...);

var deferreds = [];

if($("type").val() == "something")
    deferreds.push(dfd)

if($("other").val() == "somethingElse")
    deferreds.push(dfd2)

$.when.apply( $, deferreds )
  .then( callback, failureCallback );
```

ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Or rather `var deferreds = [$.ajax(...)];` and then `deferreds.push($.ajax(...))`.  He wants to make more than one AJAX call.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm unsure what you mean. You want to init the array with the deferred, and the push the same deferred into it again? I was trying to write the code above such that the OP could easily introduce more deferred objects with more conditions, in case his example was a simplication. If I've missed the boat, please let me know.

Comment: You want to push 2 deferreds into the array.  He's making 2 ajax calls.  One outside the `if` and one inside the `if`, both need to be in array.

Comment: .apply - that's the missing key! Thanks!!

Comment: Notice that the code in this answer does *always make* two ajax calls, but only conditionally *waits* for some of them.

Comment: Very true. Depending on the situation, it could make more sense to make the AJAX calls contingent on satisfying some condition.

Answer (score 1):

To do what the question calls for, (execute one call, then optionally call the second), Mister Epic's answer can be modified as per below.  Basically, I have wrapped the ajax calls inside functions, so that dfd2 is only called if the condition is true.

```
var dfd = function () { 
   $.ajax(...); 
};
var dfd2 = function () { 
    $.ajax(...); 
};

var deferreds = [];

deferreds.push(dfd())

if($("type").val() == "something")
    deferreds.push(dfd2())

$.when.apply( $, deferreds )
  .then( callback, failureCallback );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in doing this with the Q.js library;
http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

```
$ajax(...).then(function(val){
     if($("type").val() == "something") { return $.ajax(...);}
)};
```